# Azure Databricks Pyhton defining list gives "name 'Any' is not defined"

Tags: azure-databricks

I want to define a list of customers in Azure Databricks using Python.

```
customers: list[Any] = []
```

This gives error:

```
NameError: name 'Any' is not defined
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1> in <module>
---> 1 customers: list[Any] = []

NameError: name 'Any' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this the answer above by Abhishek Khandave misses the point. OP is trying to type a list of customers using the `Any` type in Python.

First, you don't have to do this since typing your list as:

```
customers: list = []
```

will implicitly type the list contents as `Any`. But if you want to do this anyways, you have to import `Any` from `typing`:

```
from typing import Any
customers: list[Any] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a list of customers you can simply use below code

```
customers = []
```